# Jquery + GSAP access locally calculated value from onComplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

How can I pass or update a variable and its value from a function that is triggered **onComplete** (when a certain animation is completed.)

The whole action happens inside of the onClick function which is presented below:

```
//Trigger animation on offer_button click
$offer_button.on('click', function (e) {
    //Vars:
    var $location = $(this).attr('href'),
        $dividerW = $('#divider').width(),
        $offer_headerW = $('#offer_header').width();


    e.preventDefault();

    $text_container.removeClass('reversing');

    //Nadajemy kontenerowi stan aktywny - KROK 1
    $text_container.addClass('playin');


    //display loader and then content function
    function completedFnc() {

        $content_wrapper.html('<div class="loader"><div class="uil-ring-css" style="transform:scale(0.51);"><div></div></div></div>');
        $content_wrapper.load($location + ' ' + '.ajax_content', function () {
            $content_wrapper.hide().fadeIn('slow');
            $content_wrapper.addClass('animation_complete');
            $('#ajax p').hyphenate('pl');
            $text_container.removeClass('playin');
        });

    }


    //place where animation, loader and content is called or not..
    if ($content_wrapper.hasClass('animation_complete')) {

        if ($(this).hasClass('data_retrieved')) {
            console.log('Content is already loaded. No need to refresh it.');
        }
        else {
            $offer_button.removeClass('data_retrieved'); //usuwamy klasę z poprzedniego przycisku
            $(this).addClass('data_retrieved');  //dodajemy klasę do ostatnio klikniętego przycisku
            completedFnc(); //wyświetlamy loader i wczytujemy treść (na końcu dodajemy klasę 'animation_complete')
            console.log('Animacja już wykonana, tylko ładujemy treści');

        }
    }
    else {


        //local vars
        var introduction = $('.introduction'),
            introductionH = introduction.outerHeight(),
            offer_containerH = $offer_text_container.outerHeight(),
            newWidth;


        function updateW() {
            //Calculate inner width for offer content
            var text_containerW = $text_container.width(),
                col1 = $('#offer_header').width(),
                col2 = $('#divider').width();

            newWidth = (text_containerW - col1 - col2 - 20) / text_containerW * 100;

        }


        console.log(newWidth);

        //Offer CSS calculating
        introduction.css({
            'height': introductionH + 'px'
        });
        $offer_text_container.css({
            'min-height': offer_containerH + 'px'
        });


        //Animation settings
        $anime = new TimelineMax({paused: true})
            .to('.button_row', 0.2, {opacity: 0})
            .to('.introduction', 0.4, {height: 0, autoAlpha: 0, display: 'none'})
            .to($text_container, 0.6, {
                transformPerspective: 1000, autoAlpha: 1, width: $value + 'px', onComplete: updateW
            }, 'now!')
            .to($image, 0.3, {opacity: 0, autoAlpha: 0}, 'now!')
            .to('.button_row a', 0.4, {marginTop: 0})
            .to('.button_row div.columns ', 0.4, {width: 12.5 + '%'})
            .to('.button_row', 0.4, {opacity: 1, delay: 0.2})
            .to($content_wrapper, .6, {css: {display: 'relative', minHeight: 200 + 'px'}})
            .to($switch, .6, {y: 35 + 'px', onComplete: completedFnc})
            .to('#offer_text', .4, {width: newWidth})
            .to($switch, .6, {
                opacity: 1,
                scale: 1,
                transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
                transformPerspective: 1000,
                autoAlpha: 1
            });


        $anime_small = new TimelineMax({paused: true})
            .to('.introduction', 0.4, {height: 0, autoAlpha: 0, display: 'none'})
            .to($content_wrapper, .6, {css: {display: 'relative', minHeight: 200 + 'px'}})
            .to($switch, .6, {y: 35 + 'px', onComplete: completedFnc})
            .to($switch, .6, {
                opacity: 1,
                scale: 1,
                transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
                transformPerspective: 1000,
                autoAlpha: 1
            });

        if ($(window).width() >= 641) {
            $anime.play();
        }
        else {
            $anime_small.play();
        }

        $offer_button.removeClass('data_retrieved');

        $(this).addClass('data_retrieved');
        //$text_container.removeClass('reversing');
    }
});
```

Below is where I believe the issue is occurring:

```
else {


        //local vars
        var introduction = $('.introduction'),
            introductionH = introduction.outerHeight(),
            offer_containerH = $offer_text_container.outerHeight(),
            newWidth;


        function updateW() {
            //Calculate inner width for offer content
            var text_containerW = $text_container.width(),
                col1 = $('#offer_header').width(),
                col2 = $('#divider').width();

            newWidth = (text_containerW - col1 - col2 - 20) / text_containerW * 100;

        }


        console.log(newWidth);

        //Offer CSS calculating
        introduction.css({
            'height': introductionH + 'px'
        });
        $offer_text_container.css({
            'min-height': offer_containerH + 'px'
        });


        //Animation settings
        $anime = new TimelineMax({paused: true})
            .to('.button_row', 0.2, {opacity: 0})
            .to('.introduction', 0.4, {height: 0, autoAlpha: 0, display: 'none'})
            .to($text_container, 0.6, {
                transformPerspective: 1000, autoAlpha: 1, width: $value + 'px', onComplete: updateW
            }, 'now!')
            .to($image, 0.3, {opacity: 0, autoAlpha: 0}, 'now!')
            .to('.button_row a', 0.4, {marginTop: 0})
            .to('.button_row div.columns ', 0.4, {width: 12.5 + '%'})
            .to('.button_row', 0.4, {opacity: 1, delay: 0.2})
            .to($content_wrapper, .6, {css: {display: 'relative', minHeight: 200 + 'px'}})
            .to($switch, .6, {y: 35 + 'px', onComplete: completedFnc})
            .to('#offer_text', .4, {width: newWidth})
            .to($switch, .6, {
                opacity: 1,
                scale: 1,
                transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
                transformPerspective: 1000,
                autoAlpha: 1
            });
```

I'll try to briefly explain how the above code works (or how I *think* it works).

When you click the button you tween (or animate, if you're not familiar with **GSAP**) a width of a container from 50% to about 90%. When it is done, the function `updateW` is called; this function calculates the new width for a div with text inside of our container.

Before starting an animation, the div with text has about 67% width and when the animation is finished it should be updated to about 84% (depending on the value retrieved from `updateW`).

Despite a few hours of trying namespaces, global vars, local vars I am unable to pass `newWidth` value from `updateW` when it's finished; it's always returning `undefined`.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `updateW()` is firing? Looks like you're defining it but not actually calling it.

Comment: Please look at the GSAP at the 3rd .to($text_container... - you have updateW at the end. It's calculating well. If I add console.log(newWidth) at the end of updateW it will show the right value.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a fiddle of this please? quite a lot is going on here so a little difficult to understand, for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using css **calc()**

All what have to be done was to add a new css class with the following property **calc(100% - 188px)**.

Very simple, yet effective.

My question about how to pass the variable value between function is still unsolved but no longer needed